# How can I use the JSON result of org-babel in curl?

Tags: org-babel

I first define

```
#+NAME: 01H7T457WEWS07WD5T05BS5CN9
#+begin_src shell :results verbatim replace drawer :wrap src json
echo "foo"     
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: 01H7T457WEWS07WD5T05BS5CN9
#+begin_src json
foo
#+end_src
```

..and run it

```
#+begin_src shell :var _01H7STDXTTPR3GVA6ZJFCBJTWD=01H7T457WEWS07WD5T05BS5CN9 :results verbatim :noweb yes
curl -v 'https://gnu.org/test' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$_01H7STDXTTPR3GVA6ZJFCBJTWD''
#+end_src
```

, and I get

```
curl: (3) URL rejected: No host part in the URL
```

However, if I define within, it works fine.

```
#+begin_src shell :results verbatim
export _01H7T457WEWS07WD5T05BS5CN9="foo"
curl -v 'https://gnu.org/test' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$_01H7T457WEWS07WD5T05BS5CN9''
#+end_src
```

I'm not really sure what's happening here;) Am I typing it wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: both curl shell blocks produce the same output for me: `#+RESULTS:
: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
: <html><head>
: <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
: </head><body>
: <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
: <p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.gnu.org/test">here</a>.</p>
: <hr>
: <address>Apache/2.4.29 Server at gnu.org Port 443</address>
: </body></html>

`

Comment: Yes, it works, but this message is displayed in stderr, which is a window that pops up. Do you have a curl stderr window popping up?

Comment: What works? This message is the stdout of the command, not the stderr (do the commands in a terminal and see). I got rid of the `-v` which obscured the error output. The first one does indeed fail (with a different message: `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`) but that's because the value of the env variable includes a trailing newline. Do `C-c C-v C-v` on each code block to see what  it expands to and cut and paste that into a terminal to debug.

Comment: Use `echo -n "foo"` in the first code block.

Comment: Ah, there is a newline appended to the end of it;) How come?

Comment: Because `echo` adds a newline, unless you tell it not to with `echo -n`. Didn't you see my previous comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a newline appended, so to remove the newline:

```
#+begin_src shell :var VFY4O4ap1bRqbadlm7Rhe=W2rVuySIKascv2KRq6zY7 :results verbatim
curl -v 'https://gnu.org/test' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer '`echo $_01H7STDXTTPR3GVA6ZJFCBJTWD|tr -d '\n'`'' \
#+end_src
```

or use -n, as suggested;)

Comment: Or use `echo -n` as I suggested in a comment.

Comment: yup, or that;), thanks